Language $L_{\mathbb{R}-{VS}}$ of linear functions
I am trying to design a language $L_{\mathbb{R}-{VS}}$ in which the terms can naturally be interpreted as $\mathbb{R}$-linear functions of the form $f(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i x_i$ for some $r_i \in \mathbb{R}$. It can't be $\mathbb{R}_{ring}$ because then we would have polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$, allowing non linear functions. I suppose that if instead of the reals we had a finite domain, we could define a multiplicacion function for each scalar, but in the moment we allow for general multiplication, we can build terms with powers of variables. I can't get around this.

Why not include a multiplication function for each scalar? There's no requirement that a language must be finite, or even countable.

I imagine a language has symbols to express their elements, we could assume binary for example. But I can't encode the reals in binary and then use them in a sentence for example, how can I input an infnite string inside another infinite string?

No, in general there is no restriction on what counts as a symbol. Every real number $r$ can be used as a symbol for multiplication by $r$. See here.

Indeed, as Alex’s comment said, symbols in a language is really just a set. There’s no constraints whatsoever. The reason one usually thinks of symbols as some kinds of strings over some finitary set is because that’s how most languages in practice work. After all, there is no way to actually write down (on a paper, or a computer, say) a language whose symbols cannot be represented like that. That doesn’t mean there can’t be any cases in which something more general may be appropriate. What you’re proposing here basically requires that.

Technically, you could add another sort and add symbols $0, 1, +, \times$ to that sort, to be interpreted as field operations on $\mathbb{R}$ and for that sort to be interpreted as scalars (in $\mathbb{R}$). But I’m not sure that’s really what you’re looking for here.

Also, all of these really just end up giving you a language to describe vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. Is that what you’re asking for?
